# heroku crashing no such file -- spec_helper (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, macos, heroku, rspec

I have no errors when I do git push heroku master. But on heroku open I get Application Error. So I checked heroku logs and the only thing that stuck out was:

```
2013-04-03T08:03:52+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/
activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:317:in 
`rescue in depend_on': No such file to load -- spec_helper (LoadError)
```

So I'm guessing that is the issue. Does this mean it can't find my spec_helper.rb file? It is in the spec folder.

On rails g rspec:install I get:

```
identical  .rspec
   exist  spec
identical  spec/spec_helper.rb
```

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.11'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.0.4'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.0.1'
gem 'faker', '1.0.1'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.3'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.6'
gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.2'
gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
gem 'rails_autolink', '~> 1.0.9'
gem 'rinku', '~> 1.5.0', :require => 'rails_rinku'
gem 'auto_html', '1.6.0'
gem 'acts_as_votable', '~> 0.4.0'
gem 'thumbs_up', '~> 0.6.2'
gem 'thin'
gem 'rmagick'
gem "paperclip", "~> 3.0"
gem 'nifty-generators'
gem 'fancybox-rails'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.11.0'
end

group :development do
  gem 'annotate', '2.5.0'
end

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '3.2.5'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'
  gem 'uglifier', '1.2.3'
end

group :test do
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.1.0'
  gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
  gem 'cucumber-rails', '1.2.1', :require => false
  gem 'database_cleaner', '0.7.0'
end
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks. Beginning to think there is some sort of typo somewhere in my source code, going to try uninstalling rspec.

Comment: test locally with `bundle exec rails server -e production`; check that you don't have a `.gitignore` or `.slugignore` file excluding your spec_helper file.

Comment: i got this error: "Audiospy_production" does not exist (PGError)

Comment: I did  RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake db:create and RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake db:migrate and now on bundle exec rails server -e production I get SSL connection error

Comment: in production.rb i have config.force_ssl = true

Answer (score 4):

try bundle install locally without test and development so it will produce dependencies for production and then again push to heroku

```
bundle install --without test development
```

Comment: So I type
    bundle install --without test development and then commit to git and git push heroku master. It says everything up to date, and still error appears.

Comment: I wrote "bundle install --without development test" and then ran "bundle exec rails s" and it worked fine locally

Comment: did you add 'require "spec_helper"' in your spec/controllers folder

Comment: I dont have a spec/controllers folder I have spec: helpers, models, requests. All of which require spec_helper in their files

Answer (score 2):

There were deleted files which where not being committed properly. I would see them when I wrote git status.